# how to append a javascript function with 2 variables in html?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to append into the html code a javascript function with 2 variables,
the comment variable is a string and i have problem passing it :

```
 var url = '{{URL::to('calendar/comments')}}';
 $.getJSON(url+"/"+data.id, function(data) 
 {
 ul.append("
 <li> 
    <a href='#'onclick='openmodal("+value.id+", "+value.comment+")'>       
      Modifier
    </a> 
 </li>"
 );
 });
```

but when i display in the console i get the string variable shown as a varibale
for example test and not "test" as i want and i get this error "test is not defined".

Comment: do u use blade?

Comment: is `value.id` a javascript variable?

Comment: yes i'm using blade and value.id and value.comment are js variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var url = '{{URL::to('calendar/comments')}}';
 $.getJSON(url+"/"+data.id, function(data) 
 {
 ul.append("
 <li> 
    <a href='#'onclick='openmodal("+value.id+", \""+value.comment+"\")'>       
      Modifier
    </a> 
 </li>"
 );
 });
```

You need to surround the comment with "" so when you trigger the click,
the onclick function as something like `openmodal(1,"test")` and not `openmodal(1,test)` since it would just try to call it with the `test variable which is undefined

Comment: thank you so much i've been stuck in this for so long first time i stumble upon an error like this with js !!